# HTML rendering issues after view init

Tags: angular

below is my component HTML

```
    <li *ngIf="this.currentData.length == 0">
          Data not found
    </li>
    <li
      #itemElement
      *ngFor="let item of currentData; let i = index"
      (click)="onSelectionChange(valueAccessor(item), itemElement)"
      [ngClass]="{ 'k-state-selected': isItemSelected(item) }"
    >
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        id="chk-{{ valueAccessor(item) }}"
        (focus)="onFocus(itemElement)"
        class="k-checkbox"
        [checked]="isItemSelected(item)"
      />
      <label
        class="k-multiselect-checkbox k-checkbox-label"
        for="chk-{{ valueAccessor(item) }}"
      >
        {{ textAccessor(item) }}
      </label>
    </li>
```

necessary part of compotent TS

```
    public ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.vlSubscription = this.valueListService.getValueListData(this.gridType, this.valueListObj).subscribe((data: any) => {
            this.data = data.values;
            this.currentData = this.data;
        });
    }
```

So, the problem here is until the data is returned HTML showing Data Not Found. After couple of seconds the value list is displaying. Here how can I show atleast a new text like 'loading..' until the data finished loading? Thanks.

Comment: (1). Why are the variables assigned in `ngAfterViewInit()` hook. It's perfectly fine (and quicker even) to do it in the `ngOnInit()` hook. (2). If you're using default CD strategy, it's not a good idea to bind functions in interpolation and property-bindings like `{{ valueAccessor(item) }}` and `isItemSelected(item)`. They'll be executed for each CD cycle. And you have many of such statements. Instead you could loop the array in the subscription, call the necessary functions and create new properties with their responses. And use these new properties directly in the template.

Comment: The reason is I need to call the API and load the respected column's data on clicking of a filter icon. That is the reason why I am using afterviewiniti.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add additional variable for loading:

```
 loading = true;

 public ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.vlSubscription = this.valueListService.getValueListData(this.gridType, this.valueListObj).subscribe((data: any) => {
            this.loading = false;
            this.data = data.values;
            this.currentData = this.data;
        });
    }
```

```
    <li *ngIf="this.loading">
          Loading...
    </li>

    <ng-container *ngIf="!this.loading">
      <li *ngIf="this.currentData.length == 0">
           Data not found
      </li>
      <li
        #itemElement
        *ngFor="let item of currentData; let i = index"
        (click)="onSelectionChange(valueAccessor(item), itemElement)"
        [ngClass]="{ 'k-state-selected': isItemSelected(item) }">
       ...
    </ng-container>
```